# MsSQL named JDBC template LIKE match

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm trying to run a like match using the named JDBC template with the query...

```
SELECT
    id, guid, body, summary, status_id, language_id, is_mce, content_type_id, 
    last_edited_by, locked_by, owner_id, coordinator_id, writer_id, paperless, 
    content_body_type, created, updated, locked_timestamp
FROM dbo.content
WHERE notes LIKE :notes
```

`:notes` is bound to `%test%` and unfortunately it's not returning any results.  I've checked the database and verified that this data exists.  Is this not the correct way to perform a like match?

**update**

Part of the code to generate this query...

```
    String notes = search.getNotes();
    if (notes instanceof String && notes.length() > 0) {
        if (!previousClause) {
            searchQuery.append("WHERE ");
            previousClause = true;
        }
        searchQuery.append("notes LIKE :notes AND ");
        queryMap.put("notes", "%"+notes+"%");
    }

    Collection<Category> categories = search.getCategoryCollection();
    if (categories != null && categories.size() > 0) {
        Short x = 0;
        for (Category category : categories) {
            searchQuery.append("INNER JOIN dbo.content_to_category AS content_to_category"+x.toString()+" ON (content_to_category"+x.toString()+".category_id IN (:categoryId"+x.toString()+") AND content_to_category"+x.toString()+".content_id = content.id) ");
            queryMap.put("categoryId"+x.toString(), category.getId());
            x++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using Hibernate, right? (so it seems from the `:notes` parameter syntax)

Comment: And another question: do you actually select _all_ `content` fields, or is it only a (big) subset?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume: (1) you're using Hibernate from a reasonable version; and (2) that the above selected fields are a subset of `content`'s fields.

Should go something like so:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Content.class);

// add all selected fields:
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("guid"));
projList.add(Projections.property("body"));
projList.add(Projections.property("summary"));
projList.add(Projections.property("status_id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("language_id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("is_mce"));
projList.add(Projections.property("content_type_id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("last_edited_by"));
projList.add(Projections.property("locked_by"));
projList.add(Projections.property("owner_id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("coordinator_id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("writer_id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("coordinator_id"));
projList.add(Projections.property("paperless"));
projList.add(Projections.property("content_body_type"));
projList.add(Projections.property("created"));
projList.add(Projections.property("updated"));
projList.add(Projections.property("locked_timestamp"));
crit.setProjection(projList);

// add a Restriction on notes field, using like:
crit.add(Restrictions.like("notes", "test", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

// invoke query:
List list = crit.list();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Just to be sure, the correct syntax you should be using is (relying on intuition and several blogs out there; I couldn't pin down a documentation excerpt):

```
Query query = // create long complicated query that ends with "WHERE notes LIKE :notes"
query.setParameter("notes", "%test%");
```

The reason this might not work in **your** case, is that `like` operator applies for `varchar` operands and such... And it seems from this piece of your code:

```
if (notes instanceof String && notes.length() > 0) {
```

that you're not absolutely sure about the underlying type of that field... Could it be that `notes` isn't a `String`?

Comment: that looks like a better solution than what I'm doing... but there's another level of complication in regards to switching the query type like that.  I have several loops that add inner joins to search other fields.  See original post